# Jenkins Job Build Failure

Tags: jenkins, centos, gitlab, jenkins-plugins, system-administration

After job build starts in jenkins my git-lab server's memory becomes full. Job is successful after restarting the Jenkins server.Jenkins has become too slow  Sometimes Error comes with signal 9 also. Thank-you in advance. I have attached the log of the failed build.

```
    started by user ME
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_Project
using credential ABC
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > /usr/bin/git config remote.origin.url git@myrepo:root/My_Project.git # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from git@myrepo:root/My_Project.git
 > /usr/bin/git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials 
 > /usr/bin/git fetch --tags --progress git@myrepo:root/My_Project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/My_Project_Develop^{commit} # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/My_Project_Develop^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision fbd8fcef97895366d1d08bccb22615712d1f9ef0 (refs/remotes/origin/My_Project_Develop)
 > /usr/bin/git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > /usr/bin/git checkout -f fbd8fcef97895366d1d08bccb22615712d1f9ef0
Commit message: "Update features of Software."
 > /usr/bin/git rev-list --no-walk fbd8fcef97895366d1d08bccb22615712d1f9ef0 # timeout=10
Checking for pre-build
Executing pre-build step
Checking if email needs to be generated
No emails were triggered.
[My_Project] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins6218118938138193412.sh
+ id -un
root
+ SSH_OPTS='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=5'
+ sudo git checkout My_Project_Develop
Previous HEAD position was fbd8fce... Update features of Software.
Switched to branch 'My_Project_Develop'
Your branch is behind 'origin/My_Project_Develop' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Discard old builds...
#1040 is removed because status FAILURE is not to be kept
Checking for post-build
Performing post-build step
Checking if email needs to be generated
No emails were triggered.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Do you have some code? How do you execute the source code checkout?

Comment: Yes, The web application is running.The checkout code is  ---->                 SSH_OPTS="-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=5"
sudo git checkout My_Project
sudo git pull
sudo git checkout My_Project
git branch

Comment: Usually Jenkins does this checkout automatically for your. Do you really need to execute this step manually? If yes you should try a git pull or even a reset --hard then it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pull the My_Project_Develop branch, checkout is only switching to this branch. Your branch is locally behind the server.

The message is clear:

```
Your branch is behind 'origin/My_Project_Develop' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
```

Usually this is done by Jenkins. I need more info how you run this job.

Comment: What kind of info sir ? i am pulling the My_Project_Develop branch only .@detzu

Comment: Hi , Please send the job , is it a script ? how did you configure the jenkins job ?

Comment: well, the script pulls from gitlab server My_Project_Develop branch, creates .war file and deploys in apache-tomcat in another server.